# Where can I get/buy a Futura containing all original ligatures?

Tags: fonts, ligatures

I tried many futura fonts and other ones resembling it.

Most of the fonts I tried did not contain proper ligatures (fi, fl, fj, ft etc.) as originally designed by Renner. Can someone tell me a font family closest to futura containing at least the ft ligature?

Comment: I'm not aware that there are 'official' ligatures for Futura. It's such a geometric face that ligatures would look out of place I think. But maybe they exist! Interesting question!

Comment: It looks like discretionary and standard ligatures are included when you purchase through [myfonts.com](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/futura/) (who go through linotype), though I wasn't able to get the ligatures to preview.

Comment: The Myfonts offerings do have ligatures, but it's not easy to see with Futura. There are one or two where it's more obvious, though: [example](http://i.imgur.com/M9Eh9oS.gif)